# Comparable for two classes: one generic class, one character frequency class with char character

Tags: java

I have a generic class and a character frequency class with ch character in it. I want to compare the two objects but I am getting the cannot invoke compareTo(char) to primitive type char error message.

Researching

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object obj) {
    CharacterFrequency t = null;
    if(!(obj instanceof CharacterFrequency)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Does not equal test class");        
    }
    t = (CharacterFrequency)obj;
    return character.compareTo(t.character);
}
```

Cannot invoke compareTo(char) on the primitive type char

Comment: The compareTo method works for styrings but does not work for characters or integers

Comment: In Java the primitive data types are really primitive data types and no classes!

Comment: Use [`Character.compare(character, t.character)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#compare(char,char))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Character.compare(character, t.character)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#compare(char,char)):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object obj) {
    if(!(obj instanceof CharacterFrequency)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Does not equal test class");        
    }
    CharacterFrequency t = (CharacterFrequency) obj;
    return Character.compare(character, t.character);
}
```

Comment: I did I recieved this message though : Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: nevermind I was clicking the up arrow. Done. Thanks again.